# Javascript Geometry Draw

Tags: javascript

I have to draw geometry shapes like the sample image attached here.

I check the three.js, pepper.js but, I am confused that which one is the best library for this type of work. Please help me to decide the library.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the GD library to complete these complex diagrams. Drawio helps me a lot to create the diagrams and get the coordinates of X and Y axis.

Answer (score 0):

Most processing libraries will do the job. Have a look at p5.js, it is fairly simple to get started with.

https://p5js.org/

Comment: @VikashDhiman, What is not working? Sorry I don't quite understand